# Implementing list in C - passing struct as rvalue to function

Tags: c

I want to print out a 'list' structure by printing out the first field in node struct, and then tracking the pointer field.
but I met a problem and I couldn't identify the cause:

( set-up )

```
typedef struct node {
    int first;
    struct node* rest;
} int_list;

int_list cons(int x, int_list xs) {
    int_list newlist = {x, &xs};
    return newlist;
}
```

(problematic code)

```
int_list empty = {NULL,NULL};

void print_int_list(int_list xs) {
    printf("element is : %d\n", xs.first);
    printf("next element is : %d\n", (*(xs.rest)).first);

    (commented since not related to the problem) 
                //printf("rest points to : %p\n", xs.rest);
                //if (xs.rest != NULL) print_int_list(*xs.rest);
}

int main() {
    int_list xs = cons(1,empty);
    printf("element is : %d\n", xs.first);
    printf("next element is : %d\n", (*(xs.rest)).first);

            //printf("rest points to : %p\n", xs.rest);
            //print_int_list(empty);

    print_int_list(xs);
}
```

since I've commented the recursion part, print_int_list doesn't really do anything now.

the printing codes in main and print_int_list are now exactly the same.
then I found the main part prints out:

```
element is : 1
next element is : 0 (which looks good since NULL = 0 in empty)
```

but the print_int_list prints:

```
element is : 1
next element is : 189267603
```

why is this happening? I mean why the pointer fields of 'xs changed when passed in as a parameter?

Comment: Not the actual issue but you should not send `int_list` as is to your functions, you should always send a pointer so `int_list*`.

Comment: `int_list cons(int x, int_list xs) {
    int_list newlist = {x, &xs};` : `xs` is local value.

Comment: thanks for rely :) yeah but what's happening on the stack tho I wonder.. does this mean we should never pass a struct as a rvalue to a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by BLUEPIXY in the comments, you are assigning a local variable's address to the list's "rest" field.

You should do your list-creation something like this:

```
int_list* cons(int x, int_list* xs) {
  int_list* newlist = malloc(sizeof(*newlist));
  newlist->first = x;
  newlist->rest = xs;
  return newlist;
}

...
int_list* list = cons(1, NULL);
...
list = cons(..., list); //adding elements
...
```

And your printing becomes:

```
void print_int_list(int_list* xs) {
  if (xs == NULL)
    return;
  print_int_list(xs->rest); //Here so the list is displayed in the same order as creation, last created displayed last.
  printf("element is : %d\n", xs->first);
}
```